# ¿Como cargo el contenido de una pagina $_GET en un div con javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Tengo dias tratando de cargar en un div los datos de un usuario deprendiendo al id, lo he intentado con ajax, javascript, pero al cargarlo me sale el div en blanco y en consola no aparece ningun error de js, la unica manera que me funciona es haciendo un include con php.

el link donde se carga el div: http://linkdemipag.com/info.php?usuario=1

info.php:

```html
<?php
require_once 'include/functions.php';
if (isset($_SESSION['idusuario'])){
}else{
  header("Location: logout");
}
$_GET['usuario'];
$usr = $_GET['usuario'];
?>
<html>
<head>
<?php include 'include/header.php' ?>
</head>
 <body>
<!-- ### SCRIPT ### -->
<script>
var usuario = <?php echo $usr ?>;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.load-inf').load('include/contenido-usr-mobile.php?usuario='usuario);
});
</script>

<!-- ### CONTENIDO ### -->
<div name="contenido Movil" style="margin: auto auto;" class="d-block d-sm-block d-md-none" id="load-inf">

</div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

contenido-usr_mobile.php:

```html
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
        //OBTIENE DATOS USUARIOS
$sql_inf = "SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE USUARIOS.idusuario = '" . $_GET['usuario'] . "'" ;
$result_inf = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_inf);
while($inf = mysqli_fetch_array($result_inf)) {
?>
<!--Table-->
<table id="tablePreview" class="table">
<!--Table head-->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!--Table head-->
  <!--Table body-->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td><?php echo $info['name'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $info['lname'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $info['username'] ?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <!--Table body-->
</table>
<!--Table-->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Corrige esto `$('.load-inf').load('/dir/info?usuario='usuario)` por `$('#load-inf').load('/dir/info?usuario='+usuario)`

Comment: @RimuruTempest Gracias, eso era mi error!!! como no pude haberlo visto Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Quieres añadir un div al documento con javacript?

Te recomiendo añadirlo usando appendChild sobre el elemento.

```
var MIDIV = document.getElementById("ID_DE_MI_DIV");
var PADRE = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
PADRE.appendChild(MIDIV);
```

Esto es suficiente. Te lo puse en lineas separadas pero puedes hacerlo todo en una sola expresión sin usar las variables.

Otra opción es usar el innerHTML o el outterHTML es más ineficiente y tiene algunos comportamientos extraños en casos no muy infrecuentes.

Ej:

```
PADRE.innerHTML = MIDIV.innerHTML;
```

También puedes simplemente hacer echo dentro del contendor padre no?

```
<body>
<?= "<div>lo que sea</div>" ?>
</body>
```

No tengo de todo claro que intentas hacer.